# Handling database create / update operation for concurrent REST API calls in Django

Tags: mysql, django, multithreading, transactions, locking

This is more of a follow up thread though the question is very generic. I have a Django web application with REST API (implemented with tastypie) accessed through Apache web server.

I am adding API call logging functionality so that for every call to the web application I will be creating an entry in a specific application log table in MySQL database.

User base of this application is limited. I am not expecting large volume of concurrent API calls at this point or near future.

I have the following options:

`1.  multithread locking`

```
2. multiprocess locking mechanisms
3. ORM transaction or data base locking
```

I am not sure if I should use any locking feature at all for wrapping MySQL db entry creation / update operations.

How are these kind of cases anyway dealt with for large volume of concurrent POST API calls in Django web applications?

Thanks,